# MSSQL - Node - Memory leak

Tags: node.js, sql-server, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I created a Node API that query a Microsoft SQL Server. I am using Node 10.13.0 with MSSQL 5.1.0. I've made a module to execute query easily.

```
module.exports = async function executeQuery(query, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
            let request = pool.request();
            if (typeof params != "undefined") {
                Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key) {
                    request.input(key, params[key]);
                });
            }
            return request.query(query);
        }).then(result => {
            sql.close();
            resolve(result.recordset);
        }).catch(err => {
            reject(err);
            sql.close();
        });
    });
};
```

I discovered I had a memory leak because the memory keeps increasing when people are using the Node API. I did some Heap Snapshots with the DevTools, used `--inspect`. I think this is related to my MSSQL module that query my Microsoft SQL Server. I do not know much about Node DevTools in Chrome, but I can see there is a lot of `()` in *(closure)*. They all contain the same object, and inside of it there is a reference of `pool in ConnectionPool`, which are my variables.

Am I missing something? Do I badly close connection? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your example code shows confusion between `async` and `return new Promise()`. Choose either one or the other and use it. And, it looks like you want to close your *pool* when you're done. Use `pool.close()` rather than `sql.close()` for that.

Comment: You were exactly true. I removed the `async` word, and changed to `pool.close()`. No more increasing memory, perfect!